# Knockout 'with' binding and select2 in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, binding, jquery-select2, jquery-dialog

**Problem:**

The select2 jQuery plugin does not work when used on a jQuery dialog nested under an element that uses the knockout `with` databinding. Remove the `with` binding and the select2 works fine. If `with` is bound to a nested property then it stops working.

**Background:**

So I must have battled for the best part of 3 hours trying to get select2 to work on a jQuery dialog form....talk about pi$$ing up the proverbial wrong tree, I thought it was purely jQuery dialog and select2. It probably worked from the very start with the `_allowInteraction` fix. Until I broke the problem right down to simple steps and teh cause started to reveal itself. Problem is with the `with` binding.

**Disclaimer**

Apologies as I work for an asinine company that blocks jsFiddle. Also I have broken down my implementation for illustration purposes as the actual model is quite large.

```js
// models

function Department() {
  this.name         = ko.observable('dept1');
  this.selectedTeam = ko.observable( new Team() );
}
    
function Team() {
  this.name = ko.observable('team1');
}
    
function MainModel() {
  this.department = new Department();
  this.showTeam   = function() { 
    $('#addTeamDialog').dialog('open');
  };
}

// setup

ko.applyBindings( new MainModel() );
     
$('#addTeamDialog').dialog({
  // fix allow select2 to work on the jq dialog
  _allowInteraction: function (event) {
    return !!$(event.target).is(".select2-input") || this._super(event);
  }  
});
     
$('#someList').select2({
  data: [
    { id: 0, text: 'enhancement' },
    { id: 1, text: 'bug' },
    { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' },
    { id: 3, text: 'invalid' },
    { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: showTeam">Add Team</button>

<div id="addTeamDialog">
  <fieldset data-bind="with: department">
    
    <div class="lite-dialog-field">
      <div class="label">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="hidden" id="someList" />
      </div>    
    </div>
        
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Removing the `data-bind` on the `fieldset` and select2 works fine.

When the `data-bind` on the `fieldset` is set to `department` the select2 works fine.

When the `data-bind` on the `fieldset` is set to `department.selectedTeam` select2 doesn't working.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't quite seem to be enough to reproduce your scenario (e.g. there's no `select`s or related code of any kind?).

Comment: What gives? The hidden input on the markup with id someList is the container for the select2 control. In the setup section you can see I call $('#someList').select2({..}). This converts this element to select2 list. Am I missing something? Harsh downvote....

Comment: I stand corrected. Apologies. - I've tweaked your question a bit, otherwise the system wouldn't let me undo my vote. I've also retracted my close vote as I now see I didn't put in enough effort to use posted code to repro the issue (though I'm still not 100% sure how to do so, but others may see things clearer and be able to help).

Comment: Jeroen - thanks for the apology and the retraction.

Comment: I took the liberty of reworking your code into a runnable stack snippet. This should take some out of the guesswork out and will hopefully lead to more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you work with Knockout, it's highly recommended to wrap external libraries such as select2 in bindings. While you only initialize them once, bindings such as `with`, `template` or `foreach` can modify the DOM at any time after that.

You face the danger of either

1. initializing select2 too early when Knockout hasn't rendered anything yet, or
2. Knockout throwing away and re-rendering the markup at a later point, so that your select2 is suddenly not bound any longer

For example, this would happen when `Department.selectedTeam` is changed.

I've found a quick and dirty select2 binding from Knockouts' [rniemeyer himself here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/R8UF5/). Other than that, I only changed the select2 markup into a standard `<select>` and made `MainModel.department` into a proper observable for the sake of consistency and safety.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var options = ko.toJS(valueAccessor()) || {};
      setTimeout(function() { 
          $(element).select2(options);
      }, 0);
    }
};

// models

function Department() {
  this.name         = ko.observable('dept1');
  this.selectedTeam = ko.observable( new Team() );
};
    
function Team() {
  this.name     = ko.observable('team1');
  this.values   = ["red", "grey", "blue"];
  this.selected = ko.observableArray(["blue"]);
};
    
function MainModel() {
  this.department = ko.observable( new Department() );
  this.showTeam   = function() { 
    $('#addTeamDialog').dialog('open');
  };
};

// setup

ko.applyBindings( new MainModel() );
     
$('#addTeamDialog').dialog({
  // fix allow select2 to work on the jq dialog
  _allowInteraction: function (event) {
    return !!$(event.target).is(".select2-input") || this._super(event);
  }  
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: showTeam">Add Team</button>

<div id="addTeamDialog">
  <fieldset data-bind="with: department().selectedTeam">
    
    <select data-bind="options: values,
                       selectedOptions: selected, 
                       select2: { placeholder: 'pick some colors' }">
    </select>
        
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks janfoeh. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. The depth of the property used with the 'with' binding context seems to be affecting whether the select2 control works or not. I take on board your comment about wrapping all external libraries in a binding and will convert mine to that just as soon as I can understand and fix this issue

Comment: @AlanAlcock I'm a bit confused from your comment whether you have tried using select2 through a binding or not? Because that was the core of my answer.

Comment: janfoeh - in my haste I didn't study your response correctly but this did actually solve the problem and more importantly taught me to appreciate and wrap external libraries in binding handlers. Many thanks for your help.